# using dyalog apl to access )fns function in a script function

Tags: apl, dyalog

I'm trying to use Dyalog APL to generate a function list from within a startup script using:
   `⍎ ')fns'`

but get this error:

⍎VALUE ERROR

Using `⍎ ')fns'` in a latent expression script in APLX is not a problem, but I get clobbered doing the same thing in Dyalog.

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- the `)`-commands are called "[system commands](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/System%20Commands/Introduction.htm)" and their only sensible use is in the APL-Session, not in user-defined functions (because they are just "commands", they do not return a result.)
- to get the equivalent of `)fns`under program-control, use [⎕NL](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/nl.htm) 3 or (my preferred way) `⎕NL-3` which returns the result as vector of vectors. The "quad-things" are [system-functions](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/System%20Functions%20Categorised.htm) that return results.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xDsIwDEX3nsJbxVA6sHGGipnVahJa4SZRbKhyATYQCyOX60WgDVQIIf7kr6f/v9FToSKS2z1GDec71M5HQCKQRo/GirbC4EzyyliG3oU9e6z1OoOkRcpMLMumCtYCw@VWbUEcUMsC5mBraZ3lOZLwcLrm47GpilX@TuJRp6HfjYRK6XzZxZ6Xqp/HBIMAmqC5@TxEGsOLk0P1pzKhr8on)